# User has no knowledge of technical aspects - blames question is bad

Tags: discussion

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43553176/73226) was about a precise technical topic: Developing Alexa Skills.
This includes components such as the skill (like the app), aws lambda, the amazon development center, the simulation test area, and the actual hardware - amazon echo.

My question was clear in sense of naming the developed components and what I had successfully tested and what not.It was mainly about why it is not working on the hardware.

As I could see from the comments the user has given he had no knowledge about the whole environment.
He just kept stating, that the question is "unparseable", I will quote him:

> For a start, someone with English as their first language will read
>   "Alexa skill" as a skill (i.e. ability) in using Alexa. And your 3rd
>   paragraph is unparseable

Actually that is a wrong statement. It is only true if you have absolutely  no clue that Alexa skill is nothing more like mobile app. 
Just because I don't know what something is - I can't make my own misunderstanding a problem of the question.

The 3rd paragraph was:

> If I test it from the skill - everything is good. If I do my test from  the lambda - everything is good.

Let's have a look at it:

> If I test it from the skill

If you have knowledge about developing alexa skills you know what this means: It is the simulation test inside the skill at the amazon development center.

> If I do my test from the lambda..

Skills need two components: The alexa skill and AWS Lambda. If you know this, you know that the test from the lambda is the built-in Test-Suite of AWS Lambda.

I am very angry about the way a user uses his own incompetence to close questions just because he does not understand the main content and information that is given.

Comment: I can see why. Your question looks pretty clear to me, and I've never owned an Echo nor developed for the Alexa platform. Only thing missing is the code for the skill itself that you say doesn't seem to be working on your Echo.

Comment: As one of the 5 people who closed it.  The problem is that the English is barely comprehensible.  So incomprehensible that I thought he was asking about Alexa training courses.

Comment: @Stephen C: I'm going to put the blame on Amazon for that. They literally call these things "Alexa skills", with a small s. Something about teaching Alexa - as part of the whole personal assistant thing. I wonder if the question would benefit from a primer on what Alexa skills are.

Comment: @BoltClock I can understand if you ask for code and I would be willing to show - but the two Test-suites that amazon offers show that there is no error in the code. There is nothing that needs to be debugged. 
The question was more about "what step is missing that I don't know in Order to have the "app" running on the Echo". Which I thought was pretty clear for people that have already knowledge in developing those skills.

Comment: Actually no Stephen - because that is the thing where you need knowledge. Alexa Skill is the whole thing, lets call it app.
The skill is a little module inside amazon development center. The lambda is the business logic inside AWS Lambda as a Function Module.
If I just call it skill but mean the app - this leads to confusion for people that see the difference

Comment: Using the proper [tags] on a question is very, *very* important.  You use them to select the audience that is expected to understand what you are talking about and likely to provide you with an answer.  Using [java] was not a good idea.

Comment: Hans: I chose the amazon-echo tag. I chose java because you (can) use java to code your aws lambda. My chose was influenced by hoping that experienced aws lambda developers know a little thing that I as a beginner don't know.

Comment: Keep comments civil please.

Comment: @Stefan the English in your question is perfect. The issue is that lots of people are looking at the question that don't know what an "Alexa Skill" is and they think you are saying something incorrectly. You need to narrow your target audience to people that know about AWS stuff. The best way to do that is to remove the Java tag. I understand why you think the Java tag makes sense, but given the way Stack Exchange works that tag is going to cause you problems. Also, in order to receive help you need to include more information in your question, like your actual code.

Answer (score 10):

Your question could be better and I know nothing about Java or any of the other tags.

Here are some phrases from your question and my suggestions to improve it:

> The lambda is working fine on EU/Ireland;

How did you verify that it is working? Did you run a check from the API? Is there a screenshot that you can share? Why do you explicitly state it works on EU/Ireland? It doesn't for other regions? Do you need it to be run in that region?   That will help the users do understand what you're talking about to check that your assumption is correct.

> The skill is set up. It shows also on my alexa app on my own skills for my echo.

Again, it might help to show or explain how you reached this conclusion.

> If I test it from the skill - everything is good. If I do my test from the lambda - everything is good.

Again, what is that magic test you perform?  That will help others to verify that you indeed didn't miss any steps.

Lastly about the tags you used. Although you can develop this stuff in Java, there is no Java involved in this question, so it is not clear why or how Java is related to this problem. If you feel it is relevant then you better elaborate a bit what you expect from knowledgeable Java tag followers.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback - this is something I can use (I am serious!)