# Is it okay to answer a question that is partially, but not wholly, unclear?

Tags: discussion

Please consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596186/57611) to a question from 2011. I added this answer today originally because all the answers on the page were misleading in an important aspect. After perfectly good push-back, I updated my answer to actually completely address the original poster's question instead of just the one problem with the other answers.

Now I'm receiving some additional push-back that because I said the asker's statements didn't make sense, I shouldn't answer but should close the question as "unable to tell what you're asking". However, I see a distinction between "unable to tell, at all, what you're trying to ask in a way that prevents me from answering" and "unable to tell what your exact misconception is, but I think I can definitively clear up your confusion."

If the question is so bad (it has 5 upvotes) then indeed it should be closed. Additionally, if all the answers are improper because they can't possibly tell what's being asked, should they not receive downvotes like my answer did?

I'm not asking for your upvote. I'm merely asking if you think that my answer is appropriate. I think it's a very informative answer, and I'm pretty darn sure it's correct (feel free to point out any errors in it).

Remember the scenario at the beginning of Stack Overflow where people were trying to figure out if duplicate questions should be deleted, or if they should be closed? The answer from on high came back that they should be linked, and closed, not deleted, because there's value in the differently-worded questions being accessible to people using search engines, who may use the terms from one question rather than the other.

I see this as similar. The question may not be stellar, but it presents a clear enough problem (confusion between static and singleton and how one or the other can or should be used) that a good answer is of value to anyone else searching the Internet for these terms together.

Comment: Ask yourself: "Is this question and answer going to help future readers".

Comment: Looks like you've been away for a while.  Things changed.  It is unclear to me how the word "unclear" even got into the discussion, the Q is pretty crystal.  But is a Red Button word today.  Prevailing theory right now is that intentionally not answering "unclear" questions will help to fight off the deluge of bad questions.  I'm still waiting for the outcome.  Everybody adapts, questioners got a lot smarter about it and I personally answer about 95% of the questions I see in a comment.  Interesting effort btw, I'm 140/400 closer to be able to twitter.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you elaborate on what you mean by "interesting effort"?

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, that's what I believe is true--the question and my answer will help future readers. As potentially confusing as the question is, well, that's okay, because the people who need this explanation are likely to be confused themselves.

Comment: The answer is great. I do wonder if there wasn't a similar better question available which deserved that amount of invested effort on your part though... This one is really quite poor.

Comment: @Gimby I initially only posted the first two code blocks to show that now C# offers thread safe static initialization, since other answers were not showing the best current pattern (perhaps through no fault of their own, being old). But I was voted down. The weird thing is that the downvoter never reversed himself even after I remedied the flaws raised in the initial complaint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're clear on what the question is asking, then there's no reason not to answer it.  It may be the case that the question could benefit from *additional* clarity; in that case, if you can provide it through the use of edits on the OP's question (without changing their question or putting words in their mouth), then you should provide it.

Be forewarned that by saying that "you think this is unclear" puts a sizeable downvote target on your back.  Many of us take umbrage to users answering only partially clear questions.  Again, if you can make the question clearer through edits then you can mitigate that, but bear in mind that criticisms of your answer may be a bit harsher.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I can see what you mean. For what it's worth I think "doesn't make sense" isn't the same as "is unclear", because from someone's misconceptions we can often get perfectly clarity as to their confusion. Example: Q: "Since cats are just small dogs, can I feed them dog food?" A: "This doesn't make sense. Cats aren't just small dogs, and no, they have different nutrition requirements." Not unclear at all. Now, I don't honestly know what the asker's colleague meant, but I don't think I need to know in order to set him straight.

Comment: I agree. In fact, very few questions are wholly clear. I do believe the community has a responsibility to gain progressive clarity through a series of questions to the OP where the question has made a reasonable attempt to cite a problem for which there is likely to be a solution.

Comment: How does one define "wholly clear"? What's clear to one may be unintelligible to others, [and what seems off-topic to some may well be a perfectly clear and coherent question to its target audience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348282/user-has-no-knowledge-of-technical-aspects-blames-question-is-bad)...