# When is the appropriate time to use the tag "question-answering"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I saw a tag I had never seen before, [question-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question-answering). It had nothing to do with the post so I edited it to have it removed, but I also looked it up and didn't see any recent posts with it as well. When is this tag used? Is it possible that it is unnecessary?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering

Comment: Looking at the questions it's generating, I'm thinking "never", but I could be convinced otherwise.

Comment: In the context that @Hans refers to it does make sense. It seems to be adequately misused. I think a clean-up is in order, along with a tag wiki/excerpt update that makes it more clear when the tag should be used instead of just a blurb about what question answering is in the context of NLP/AI. Of course, if there are no reasonable questions about question answering in the context of NLP/AI when all is said and done, then we have our answer on whether or not the tag should exist _right now_.

Comment: Doesn't the tag wiki tell you all you need to know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The appropriate usage of a tag *should* be documented in the tag wiki excerpt, which is shown to you as an inline pop-up when you are selecting a tag.

If this information is *not* found in the excerpt, then someone who is knowledgeable needs to suggest an edit that fills it in.

In this case, the tag *does* have an excerpt, [suggested and approved way back in late-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20751114/revisions), so the appropriate time to use the tag [question-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question-answering) is when you have a question about

> …the computer task of mechanically answering questions posed in natural language.

This is [a term of art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering) in computer science—specifically, within the field of natural language processing (NLP)—so that's what we named the tag. It obviously does not mean that you want your question answered. That's not what tags are for. They describe the *content* of the question.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348282/user-has-no-knowledge-of-technical-aspects-blames-question-is-bad

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to everyone as well - I honestly was just so surprised by the tag, and reading the wiki on it meant nothing to me.